# Algebra question involving negative bases and fractional exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question appeared on a math test and after the test we asked different teachers who gave different responses.
The confusing part is whether or not the -32 part evaluates to (-16) or (16)

The answer is either 3 or 35

Question (note exponents are the entire fraction):

$81^{1/2}+\sqrt[3]8-32^{4/5}+16^{3/4}$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths. Also, what do you understand about the problem, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: So, how is there a negative base? You subtract a term, true, but this subtracted term has a positive base.

Comment: You have $-32^{4/5}=16$ and not $(-32)^{4/5}$. Thus the base is positive.

Comment: @callculus42 $-32^{4/5}=-16.$

Comment: Remember PEMDAS. $x - 32^{4/5}$ means $x + - (32^{4/5})$ and not $x + (-32)^{4/5}$.